# Python, opencv matchtemplate error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Hi I'am trying to use matchTamplate func but its giving thar eror

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((depth == 0 || depth == 5) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2) in cv::matchTemplate, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp, line 1102
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "templatematch.py", line 10, in 
>       res = cv2.matchTemplate(img2gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
>   cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1102: error: (-215) (depth == 0 || depth == 5) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function cv::matchTemplate

Here is tho code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread("tempmatch1.jpg")
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread("tempmatch2.jpg")
w, h,_ = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img2gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.80
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow("detected", img)

k= cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k==27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the error is telling you that the template isn't compatible with the image it's being applied to. In this case, a color template and a grayscale image.

Instead of

```
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img2gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

try

```
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

Comment: Thank you, its perfectly worked and i just want to say it work when i did template grayscale to but its give better results when I do like you say

Comment: If color isn't important for matching, a grayscale template is probably a tiny bit faster, too.