# Can someone help me with this OpenCV error? I'm trying to use openCV's matchTemplate to match a screenshot from a live capture to a local .jpg image

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching, game-automation

Here is the error message:

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'`

This is the function that the error occurred in, in line
`result = cv.matchTemplate(biome_img, self.husk_image, self.method)`

```py
def find(self, biome_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
    result = cv.matchTemplate(biome_img, self.husk_image, self.method)

    locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
    locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))

    rectangles = []
    for loc in locations:
        rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), self.img_w, self.img_h]

        rectangles.append(rect)
        rectangles.append(rect)

    rectangles, weights = cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=1, eps=0.5)
```

This is how I called the function:

```py
while True:
    screenshot = wincap.window_capture()
    points = visionObject.find(screenshot, 0.5, 'rectangles')
```

I've tried changing them to uint8 and float32 but it didn't work.

Comment: Both images must be the same in either uint8 or float32. Also the two images must have the same dtype. They must be the same as either 1 or 3 channels. Also the template must not be larger than the image. Always check your shape and dtype on both images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, opencv matchtemplate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818032/python-opencv-matchtemplate-error)

Comment: please review [ask]. you _should_ disclose that you're trying to "automate" Minecraft.